# exception handling for URL check is not working

Tags: python, python-requests

When I try a URL manually in a browser, I see below error
[image]

I am trying to capture the error in my code using exception handling:

```
with requests.session() as session:

try:
    f.write('URL 1\n')
    page = session.get(url=url)
    page.raise_for_status()  # If successful, no Exception

except HTTPError as e:
    f.write('*****************Attention*****************\n')
    f.write(f'HTTP error occurred: {e}\n')
    f.write('*******************************************\n\n\n')
```

However, my code is not able to capture the failure, rather when I execute my code, I see below response:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1240, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1286, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1235, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 1006, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 946, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001A89D8155B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're handling the wrong type of exception, you're catching `HTTPError`, but a `ConnectionRefusedError` was thrown and `ConnectionRefusedError` is not a `HTTPError` (by inheritance)

Catch both, if you expect either:

```
try:
    # your code
except (HTTPError, ConnectionRefusedError):
    # deal with it
```

If you need to deal with them differently, catch them separately:

```
try:
    # your code
except HTTPError as e:
    # deal with http error
except ConnectionRefusedError:
    # deal with connection refused error
```

Note that the `as e` bit will allow you to refer to the exception (as `e`, in this example) and this will allow you to find out what went wrong or tell the user.

Comment: Hi, I tried the solution "except HTTPError, ConnectionRefusedError:", but I have been receiving the below error:

  File "auto.py", line 17
    except HTTPError, ConnectionRefusedError:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Ah, sorry, those should be in parentheses, my bad.